# Default ModelForm Field (Foreign Key) From URL Parameter

Tags: python, django, modelform

I have a URL which contains a reference_id, this reference ID is getting passed to my HTML file to default the value of the ModelForm.  My problem is that the field ModelForm field which I am defaulting is a Foreign Key to another model.  The way that I am currently doing it, through the HTML file, the form does not submit due to the above. I'm wondering how I can set this form field to default to the parameter passed through the URL, make it read only, and still have it post to the Model. In the form posted below, it is the 'reference' field which I am attempting to default and in the HTML the  tag is how I am currently doing it. Any thoughts or alternatives are more than welcome.

MODELS.PY

```
class Manifests(models.Model):

    reference = models.ForeignKey(Orders)
    cases = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    count = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cases
```

FORMS.PY

```
class CreateManifestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Manifests
        fields = ('reference', 'cases', 'description', 'count')
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def add_manifest(request, reference_id):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest', reference_id=reference_id)

    form = CreateManifestForm()
    manifests = Manifests.objects.all()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'reference_id': reference_id,
        'manifests' : manifests,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', context)
```

ADD_MANIFEST.HTML

```
  <div class="container">
    <form method="POST">

      <br>
      <br>
      {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.reference">Reference ID: </label><br>
          <input type="text" value="{{ reference_id }}">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.description">Description: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.description}}
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.cases">Cases: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.cases }}
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.count">Count: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.count }}
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
          <br>
          <br>


      <button type="submit" name="add_mani" style="border-color: #7395AE;">Add Line</button>
    </form>
```

URLS.PY

```
url(r'^add_manifest/(?P<reference_id>\d+)/$', add_manifest, name='add_manifest'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the instance the form would create, off the top of my head in `views.py`:

```
# ... import the Orders model

def add_manifest(request, reference_id):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            try:
                order = Orders.objects.get(id=reference_id)
            except Orders.DoesNotExist:
                pass  # do error handling here
            instance.reference = order
            instance.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest', reference_id=reference_id)

    form = CreateManifestForm()
    manifests = Manifests.objects.all()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'reference_id': reference_id,
        'manifests' : manifests,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', context)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer - I'm a bit confused about how this helps my situation though...what would I do in the HTML file following your code above? I believe my issue is that the form is not valid because of the way I am defaulting a field which is a foreign key @phoibos